# Could not autowire for AmazonSQSClient

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have this service that I need to make some updates to and came across an error that I'm unfamiliar with how to tackle.

```
@Service
class AWSSQSService(
    @Value("\${aws.region:us-east-1}")
    private var regionText: String,
    @Value("\${aws.sqs.queueName}\${AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME_SUFFIX:}")
    private var queueName: String,
    private var sqsClient: AmazonSQSClient,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
)
```

In intellij, it's showing "Could not autowire. No beans of 'AmazonSQSClient' type found. " but the project builds locally + all of the tests pass with no issues. The problem is this error is causing the build to fail in buildkite so I'm trying to figure out how to get around it. I don't think you can autowire individual constructor parameters. I realize this post isn't providing more details other than describing the problem but I'm kinda at a dead end now.

Comment: If possible, please share a minimal, reproducible project sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code. First you are using ***AWS SDK for Java V1***, which is no longer recommended and considered not best practice. You should update to ***AWS SDK for Java v2***. Here is the DEV Guide.

[Developer Guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

All Java code example in [AWS COde Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) show use of V2. This is the document that should be referenced for **AWS Code examples**. Because V1 is not best practice, this code lib does not show V1 examples.

If you look at the AWS COde Lib, you will find a doc that demonstrates how to develop a Spring REST API that sends and retrieves messages by using the AWS SDK for Java (v2) and Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS).

In this example, the Service class that uses the V2 Amazon SQS Service Client is auto-wired. That is, the service class acts as an intermediary between the controller and Amazon SQS service.

See this example to learn how to successfully use Amazon SQS Java V2 API in a Spring Boot app.

[Create a web application that sends and retrieves messages by using Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sqs_example_cross_SQSMessageApp_section.html)